# how to get all documents with more than one referenced document in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

i have a model like this:

```
model User
  has_many :posts
end
```

I want to get all the Users that has more than one posts, but

```
users = User.all(:conditions => {:posts.size.gt => 0 } )
```

does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in one request in MongoDB. There are no join system. You need to do in two request.

```
# Get all user_id doing some Post
user_ids = Post.all.only(:user_id).distinct(:user_id)

# Get all user with this list of user_id
User.where(:id => user_ids)
```